# Google Plus One Button Consistency between Android and Website

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I have followed the google play service sample to added a PlusOneButton in my Android app, the plus and minus function is working well so far. Just I got a issue when user removed plus item through their +1 website (it's in Profile -> +1's) and go back to the app, the plus status won't be updated in my app, it will stay at plus status. (Looks like Play store will change the status to un-plus). I have no idea how play store did. Does anyone could give me some suggestion? And also is there any way to implement +1 feature just like play store did? Don't have to show up the popup dialog.

Following is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.plustest);

    int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
    if(errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
    } else {
        // The +1 button does not require scopes.
        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
             .clearScopes()
             .build();
    }

    /*
     * The {@link PlusOneButton} can be configured in code, but in this example we
     * have set the parameters in the layout.
     *
     * Example:
     * mPlusOneSmallButton.setAnnotation(PlusOneButton.ANNOTATION_INLINE);
     * mPlusOneSmallButton.setSize(PlusOneButton.SIZE_MEDIUM);
     */
    mPlusOneSmallButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_small_button);
    mPlusOneMediumButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_medium_button);
    mPlusOneTallButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_tall_button);
    mPlusOneStandardButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_standard_button);
    mPlusOneStandardButtonWithAnnotation = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(
         R.id.plus_one_standard_ann_button);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPlusClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time we receive focus.
    mPlusOneSmallButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    mPlusOneMediumButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL, this);
    mPlusOneTallButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    mPlusOneStandardButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    mPlusOneStandardButtonWithAnnotation.initialize(mPlusClient, URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}

@Override
public void onButtonClick(int id) {

}

@Override
public void onDashboardClick() {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    String name = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    mConnectionResult = connectionResult;

    if(!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if(requestCode == PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
    if(!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        mPlusClient.connect();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed on SDK 13 is that when you +1 your website, it is not taken into account in the app (probably kind of bug). Nevertheless, when you +1 in the app, a window appears:

- add a +1 on your website if you click ok
- remove the +1 on your website if you click cancel